# What does "no están de más" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

**Context**

Juan is looking around the house for clues. He then displays the things he found on a table. Among the things he found are two coins. He picks them up and says:

> Pero bueno, *diez pesos no están de más.*

What does this phrase mean and how is it used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Estar de más* means to be superfluous or unnecessary, so your sentence, which conveys a slight jocosity or sarcastic tone, can be translated as "*10 pesos don't do any harm*".

Answer (score 2):

It can also mean "10 pesos more or less wont make a  difference/impact/any harm".